# importing nodes from xml file

Tags: xml, ant

In my build.xml I need to create a property with name and location attributes. The location is the relative path to the xslt processor. The problem is that this path (the location attribute value) has to be imported from an `xml` file.

In this example:

```
 <property name="processor_path" location="../../library/xalan-j_2_7_2/xalan.jar"/>
```

this part: `../../library/xalan-j_2_7_2/xalan.jar` has to be extracted from here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set-up>
    <processor name="xalan" path="../../library/xalan-j_2_7_2/xalan.jar"/>
</set-up>
```

In other words, instead of manually typing the path of the processor, the build itself to read xml and when it find `set-up.processor` to read the value of attribute named path.

This is what I tried:

xml file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<processor>
    <property name="path" location="../../library/saxon-he-9-6-0-7j/saxon9he.jar"/>
</processor>
<test-case name="test-case-1">
    <object-under-test category="template" name="text-align"/>
    <parameters>
        <input name="text">text</input>
        <input name="min-lenght">8</input>
        <input name="align">left</input>
        <output name="result"/>
    </parameters>
    <criteria>
        <criterion class="equal" to="'text '"/>
    </criteria>
</test-case>
```

This is the `build.xml`:

```
 <project name="TranformXml" default="report">

 <xmlproperty file="../test-cases/test-case-1.xml" collapseAttributes="true"/>
 <property name="processor_path" location="${processor.path}"/>

 <property name="output_path" location="../test-report"/>
 <property name="input_path" location="../test-cases"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete file="stylesheet-2.xsl"/>
        <delete file="${output_path}/report.xml"/>
    </target>

    <target name="do-stylesheet-2">
       <xslt in="${input_path}/test-case-1.xml" out="stylesheet-2.xsl" style="stylesheet-1.xsl" force="true">
          <classpath location="${processor_path}" />
       </xslt>
    </target>

    <target name="do-report" depends="do-stylesheet-2">
        <xslt in="stylesheet-2.xsl" out="${output_path}/report.xml" style="stylesheet-2.xsl" force="true">
            <classpath location="${processor_path}" />
        </xslt>
    </target>

    <target name="report" depends="do-report" />
 </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand your problem. With given file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set-up>
    <processor name="xalan" path="../../library/xalan-j_2_7_2/xalan.jar"/>
</set-up>
```

and [xmlproperty task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html) :

```
<project>
 <xmlproperty file="xmlprops.xml" collapseattributes="true"/>
 <echoproperties prefix="set-up"/>
</project>
```

you'll get the property `set-up.processor.path`

output :

```
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Thu Oct 29 08:22:52 CET 2015
[echoproperties] set-up.processor=
[echoproperties] set-up.processor.name=xalan
[echoproperties] set-up.processor.path=../../library/xalan-j_2_7_2/xalan.jar
```